# How to adjust the controls for NFS Shift to deal with a braking problem

Tags: keyboard, need-for-speed-shift

I'm playing NFS Shift on my pc using my keyboard. I have kept the control setting to casual. This causes the "Assist braking" option to be high and compulsory.
[image: Assist braking option]

Now this works in a very stupid way. Very frequently when I'm driving with leading position and a sharp corner approaches the AI slows my car automatically so much that other cars behind me overtake me at blazing speeds. This gets especially annoying when there are sharp corners near the finish lines.

So I noticed that there are more controls to fine tune the way braking works by defining the **brake dead zone** and **brake sensitivity**. I can only hope that making changes to this would also affect the wonderful assist.

Question: What setting should I keep for the **brake dead zone** and **brake sensitivity** to deal with this problem?
[image: Driving control options]

**Edit:** You can open the image in a new window to see a larger size.

Comment: Could you change the handling model to something else, note the differences from Casual, and then re-do the changes you want to make it "casual without brake assist"?

Comment: @Anna Lear Ah! That was the very first thing I tried to do. Unfortunately, when we select Casual, the settings for brake assist are greyed out. So we cannot alter them.

Comment: I meant can you select a higher level ("hard" or "pro" or whatever Shift calls it), and then enable the assists you want? Does Shift have a "custom" handling mode?

Comment: @Anna Lear The braking assist is tied with the steering assist. Either you have both assists or none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The brake dead zone and brake sensitivity change how does the game react to press the break pedal or a button on your joystick. It will not change the way the game react to your keyboard steereing.
To get rid of the annoying assist, is to turn it off, or reduce it to minimum. I am not sure, but probably there is a config file that defines the distance to the curve to break, and the speed.

Comment: I fiddled around with those two settings and it actually does seem to have an effect on the keyboard too.

Comment: I cannot find any config file that will do what you are asking. Have you seen any file like this?

Comment: I was wrong. The controls do nothing for the keyboard. The dead zone is basically how much angle you can move the joystick around from the center without having any effect and the sensitivity is the setting for how much change in turning intensity is measured for slight changes in the joystick controls.